# TypeError: CryptoJS is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, cryptojs

Im working on a project in ReactJS and I want to implement the AES function from CyptoJS library. But when I perform the event that triggers the use of the AES ecrypting I recieve the following error: TypeError: crypto_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.CryptoJS is undefined

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {CryptoJS} from 'crypto-js';
export function Register(){
    var body = /* a JSON with information from the register */
    var encyMssg = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(body), "key").toString();

    return(/* HTML COMPONENT*/);
}
```

The error displays in the var encyMssg line and this script is written in a .jsx file. Any kind of solution? Thank you for your time.

SOLVED thanks a lot. The problem as several of you said was the {} in the import line; the correcto way to import the libray was:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

Comment: Are you sure, this how it is imported? Can you please cross check with the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js). i guess it should be `import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have to installed crypto-js using

`npm install crypto-js`

---

Then in your JS file import module you want to use.

`import aes from 'crypto-js/aes';`

Now you can aes like below.

`aes(value, key).toString()`

---

Here is working stackblitz example.

[React Crypto AES StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-arsou2?file=src%2FApp.js)